# PHP : how to return back to previous page while closing pop up

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form submission. While i Click Submit button, will check for mandatory fields and if the fields are blank, I am opening a popup window using javascript to show error message. So once I close the popup I am not going back to previous page Instead it shows a white blank screen.

My code for verification and opening popup is :

```
<?php 

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    { 
if ($task == '' || $comments == '')
 {
 // generate error message
print "<script type='text/javascript'>";
print "window.open('error.php','new_window1','status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,menu=no,width=320,height=220');";
print "</script>";  

}
else
{
$sql3= "INSERT INTO work (task, comments, assignee, type, priority, dataum1, dataum2, status) VALUES ('$task', '$comments', '$assignee', '$type', '$priority', '$dataum1', '$dataum2', '$status')";
mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You have 2 ways:a. use javascript/jquery validation before submitting to php. b."remember" inputted fields in hidden fields and when clicked 'back' button send them back to the form

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a JS-popup you would probably want to do the mandatory-check client-side with JavaScript (keep the server-side check as well though), and then prevent the form from posting if the necessary fields aren't filled out.

Answer (score 0):

Post the form data to the same page where you have the form. And add the above validation code to the top of that page. So when a validation error occurs, the user sees a popup with the error message, but he is on the same page where the form is.